# How to make minikube server tls-curlable?

Tags: ubuntu, tls, kubernetes

I am following a tutorial to implement hyperledger fabric in kubernetes by setting up a minikube server in a kvm2 virtual machine while on an Ubuntu 18.04. base operating system. At some point I need to

```
curl https://dubi/cainfo ,
```

where dubi is a host defined in /etc/hosts and pointing to the minikube server's IP, but I get following error:

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

When doing

```
curl https://dubi/cainfo -k ,
```

it works as intended and I can see a certificate. I was wondering if there is a way to make the minikube server tls-callable?

What I tried so far is to write an extension for the kubernetes service running in minikube:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: mock-server
spec:
  tls:
    - secretName: dubi-tls
      hosts:
        - dubi
  rules:
  - host: dubi
    http:
      paths:
        - path: /
          backend:
            serviceName: kubernetes
            servicePort: 443 ,
```

create a tls key with

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -sha256 -nodes -keyout dubi.key -out dubi.crt -subj "/CN=dubi" -days 365,
```

and

`kubectl apply -f kubernetes.yaml`.

Unfortunately, that does not work, I still get the error mentioned above.
Are there any errors in what I tried to do or is there a better and working way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the standard certificate ca--tls is that it only has a key and does not have a .crt entry. Creating a key pair with openssl, generating a secret, telling the ca-hlf service to use these as certificates, and adding certificate and key to /etc/ssl/certs and /etc/ssl/private did the trick.